# Azure digital Twin UDF getting Space location

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I have location added to a space that sits 2 levels above sensor but I am finding no way with the current client reference operation to get the location as I want to enrich the telemetry with space location information.

I have used the following 
getSpaceMetadata
getSpaceExtendedProperty(spaceId, propertyName) //As it is not extended property

I need the functionality similar to this

https://urlofdigitaltwin/management/api/v1.0/spaces/633a40d6-790d-4bd5-92c5-1cc8b1a86141/?includes=location

Please let me know if there is a way I can always do it inside some other azure service by going and reading these separately.

- space with location

  - device
  - sensor
    -matcher
    -udf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great question! Azure Digital Twins is undergoing continuous improvement. I hope you'll find the documentation significantly improved.

Assuming you have extracted the location ID from the sensor or device, you can find the associated `parentSpaceId`:

```
{
    "id": "aa000aaa-a0a0-0000-a0aa-00000a000aa0",
    "name": "Example Room",
    "typeId": 14,
    "parentSpaceId": "1b1b1111-b1b1-1111-111b-1b1b11b11111",
    "subtypeId": 13,
    "statusId": 12
}
```

From there you can call the top-level space directly. You can combine that operation with several API query parameters such as **traverse**, **minLevel**, and **maxLevel** which should allow you to fetch everything you need in one call.

Two new resources that describe those API operations are now available:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/how-to-navigate-apis
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/how-to-query-common-apis

Thanks!

Comment: Does this work in the context of the UDF was more that I was after the ability to have the udf fetching those details

Comment: If I understand your original question more fully, you can use the same API features above within a UDF. You could, for instance, call an API using the query features describe above and traverse to find the desired extended type or subtype.

Comment: A few code samples that demonstrate how to work with complex UDF operations live here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-facilities-setup and here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/digital-twins-samples-csharp/tree/master/occupancy-quickstart/src/actions/userDefinedFunctions. The second link includes a UDF itself, the rest of the code (C#) interacts with the DT API's and handles UDF deployment.

Comment: You might find it more convenient to do that kind of API traversing within your wrapping code (in the examples that'd be equivalent to the C# code).